# Como obter o evento "end" do http com o fetch API

Tags: javascript

Estou querendo utilizar o fetch da API ao inves do modulo http(node). Porém, não estou conseguindo pegar o fim da requisição.

```
var req = http.request(options, res => {
    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    res.on('data', () => {
      //como entro nesse trecho com o fetch ???
    });
    res.on("end", () => {
      //como entro nesse trecho com o fetch ???
    });
  });
```

Quero pegar esses "eventos" com o fetch ???

```
fetch(_end, options)
                .then(res => {
                    res.on('data', () => { 
                      //Não exite esse res.on utilizando o fetch
                    });
                    res.on("end", () => {
                        //Não exite esse res.on utilizando o fetch.
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    ...
                });
```

Alguém pode me dar alguma dica de como fazer isso utilizando a API fetch.

Comment: Queres usar fetch no browser ou no Node?

Comment: fetch no bowser

Comment: utilizar no browser chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `fetch` e o `request` tem diferentes APIs. O fetch retorna uma promise e o controlo do estado é feito pela [API da promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Instance_methods) com o `.then`, `.catch` e `.finally`; enquanto que o `request` funciona com eventos.

Assim podes escolher correr código no:

- `then`: chamado quando tudo corre bem
- `catch`: chamado quando algo corre mal (ele deve estar sempre definido para o código não parar caso haja um erro)
- `finally`: chamado independentemente de a Promise ter sido resolvida ou rejeitada

Exemplo:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/')
  .then(async response => {
    const dados = await response.json();
    console.log('Tudo correu bem!');
    console.log('Qtd de dados:', dados.length);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Houve um erro!', err))
  .finally(() => console.log('The end!...'));
```

Comment: Somente uma dúvida: Se o response retornar um arquivo. E for feito o dados.length como você fez. Esse será o valor do tamanho do arquivo ?

Comment: Esse dados.length é o tamanho em bytes ?

Comment: @frontend não, nesse caso seria a quantidade de caracteres no json. Para saber o numero de bites terias de converter para um binário, não tenho bem a certeza de como medir isso.

Comment: Tem como eu saber o tamanho do retorno do response em bytes ?

Comment: Será que isso resolve:

Comment: const reader = res.body.getReader();
                        let bytesReceived = 0;
                        while (true) {
                            const result = await reader.read();
                            if (result.done) {
                                console.log('Fetch complete');
                                break;
                            }
                            bytesReceived += result.value.length;
                            console.log('Received', bytesReceived, 'bytes of data so far');
                        }

Comment: @frontend é possivel. Evita `while(true)`, podes usar em vez disso `while(!result.done)`.

Comment: muito obrigado :D

Comment: será que desta forma retornará o tamanho de um arquivo correto ? fetch(url) .then(response => response.blob())
.then(data => console.log('Download ended. Bytes downloaded:', data.size))